# migrar base de datos de MySQL a postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, postgresql

tengo una base de datos en MySQL y me han pedido que ahora se use postgreSQL la pregunta como la paso? es de 12 tablas y 250 registros,
la documentacion que encuentro es antigua no se si habra nuevos metodos.

Comment: Puedes  usar pgloader, como explica la [Wiki de Postgresql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL), es muy fácil, [aquí tienes las instrucciones de instalación y de uso](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader) Una vez instalado: `$ createdb tu_base_de_datos
$ pgloader mysql://user@localhost/sakila postgresql:///tu_base_de_datos`

Answer (score 0):

La base de datos que tienes es pequeña, yo te recomendaría migrarla a mano, es decir,  recrear los esquemas de posgress uno por uno, para eso puede usar mysqldump, y pg_restore.

Sobre los datos, puedes importar los datos de mysql a un archivo XML o CSV para ello puedes hacer uso de [mysqlworkbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) como cliente de mysql.

ya en postgress puedes usar [pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) para importar los datos directamente a las tablas creadas.